# Firebase authentication - Allow login for dashboard access

Tags: firebase-security

Firebase is new for me. I get through Firebase docs and tutorials in security and I see that as long as I can access my firebase dashboard without authentication, other people can access as well. So sorry for a silly question, how could I enforce an authentication for those who want to access my firebase dashboard?

For example, given a firebase app URL, http://[appName].firebaseio.com, any users can see data structure and it is better to have an authentication to the URL.